# Opera leaves long polling socket(s) open

Tags: javascript, sockets, opera, long-polling, file-descriptor

We have a problem with long polling and opera. I myself am a c-programmer and have developed a customized http-daemon for our needs. In this case we needed a long polling server that would be able to handle large amounts of connections.

The problem is that opera somehow leaves these long polls open even after clicking some link on the site and of course opens new one. We use basic long polling technique which tries to include javascript inside iframe. This works fine with other browsers, but even if I force previous polls to close on server side, opera reopens them. This is not very good, because on high traffic site, just few opera users can cause the daemon to quickly run out of free file descriptors simply by browsing the site (because every click on the site opens a new long poll and old ones wont close). Page refresh does not cause the same, it does the right thing: close the long poll and open a new one. After closing opera, all file descriptors are closed and everything is fine again.

So, should I add some specific headers for opera in the http-daemon or is there something wrong in our javascript?

edit: Tested using version: Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; U; en) Presto/2.6.30 Version/10.63

Comment: could you post somewhere an actual piece of code. It is hard to analyze and propose you a solution without a precise example.

Answer (score 0):

> We use basic long polling technique which tries to include javascript inside iframe.

So the socket(s) in question are supplying content to the `iframe`?

It certainly seems as though Opera should be closing those connections if you click away from the page. But you might try explicitly destroying the `iframes` when leaving the page, something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    theIframe.parentNode.removeChild(theIframe);
    theIframe = undefined;
};
```

(I assume you have a reference to the iframe lying around somewhere.)

**Edit**: Or even navigating the iframe elsewhere first:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    theIframe.src = "about:blank";             // <== New bit
    theIframe.parentNode.removeChild(theIframe);
    theIframe = undefined;
};
```

Comment: I look the socket(s) at server side ;) Connections wont be closed even if you click a link that goes to other site or close the tab on your opera. Long poll connections seem to close only when you close opera process.

Comment: @Antti: I understand. What I'm saying is what happens if you try to do something (even more) explicit to get Opera to recognize that you're done with that iframe? It really should be closing them anyway, but...

Comment: Yea, it should. We will try that aproach. Our javascript guy said something similar when I told him about this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think we got it "working".. Without modifying javascript. I made specific rule for opera in the http-daemon, that it replies to old long polls with "403 Forbidden" (Why didn't i try that before is the question :P). Simple close() on those old socket(s) just made opera reopen the connection.

It's ridiculous that opera wont close those long polls even if I close the tab on the browser, I have to close the whole opera process.